# Multiple processes atomic output in linux shell

Tags: linux, bash

Is it possible to write from multiple processes to some queue in atomic manner?
For example

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                   

rm ./queue
mkfifo ./queue
curl http://www.url1.com > ./queue &
curl http://www.url2.com > ./queue &
cat ./queue
```

Output order [www.url1.com](http://www.url1.com) or [www.url2.com](http://www.url2.com) does not matter. I would like to have consistence content regardless of size. Is it possible in linux shell? Named fifo is not obligatory.

Comment: `consistence content` Please define consistent. You want it to be sequenced? `Is it possible to write from multiple processes to some queue in atomic manner?` You can use a lockfile and sequence two processes. You can use that a fifo with messages under  PIPE_BUF bytes.

Comment: I don`t want content of www.url1.com to be messed up with www.url2.com. Two http pages should go one by one

Comment: lock file is not the option, cause I need to do it in parallel. Limitation of PIPE_BUF is not enough

Comment: Yes, so you want it to be _sequenced_. One after the other. Do you want the output of url1 be before url2, the other way round, or does the order doesn't matter? `lock file is not the option, cause I need to do it in parallel` I do not understand, you have to _write_ in sequence for it to be in sequence. You can download in parallel.

Comment: the order does not matter

Comment: for multiple processes to write to one target you need some sort of traffic cop to keep the output streams from getting intertwined ("Duh, Mark!" ?); ideas include `flock` or perhaps a queuing/database system with inbuilt lock management; another, simple approach ... have each process write to it's own output file and then have the parent process the input files in the desired order; this looks (to me) like a potential [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) in that I'm wondering why you need/want a `fifo` to start with

Comment: Do you suggest to download in parallel and use lock file for every write operation? thank you for idea

Comment: continuing with the 'XY problem' theme ... the current code kicks the `curl` calls off in the background and then immediately dumps (via `cat`) the contents of the `fifo` but ... chances are pretty good the `curl` calls are sttill running (ie, haven't generated all of their content) by the time the `cat` runs so ... you 'lose' a lot of info; I realize the question is meant to be a minimal repro of what you're working on but in this case the sample code generates more questions/issues that could be pertinent in coming up with a solution to this (limited) question

Comment: `by the time the cat runs so ... you 'lose' a lot of info` Nothing will be lost - `curl` will just block if the fifo is full. From `man 7 pipe` -> `pipe  has  a limited capacity.  If the pipe is full, then a write(2) will block or ...` :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just with GNU parallel:

```
parallel --group curl ::: http://www.url1.com http://www.url2.com
```

Without GNU parallel you would lock for the output:

```
lockfile=$0
func() {
   a=$(curl "$1")
   flock "$lockfile" cat <<<"$a"
}
func http://www.url1.com &
func http://www.url2.com
wait

# with GNU xargs
export -f func
printf "%s\n" http://www.url1.com http://www.url2.com |
  xargs -P0 bash -c 'func "$@"' _
```

Comment: Could you give link to parallel documentation?
https://linux.die.net/man/1/parallel can`t find group and ::: options here

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html